# How to set default image to Android phone contact that has no previous image

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, rawcontacts, rawcontactid

I have a piece of code which updates the an Android contact´s image, the problem is that it doesn't work when the contact has no previous image. I also checked that the contact was from "Phone" account or "*@gmail.com" account. When it already has an image with these accounts I have no problem updating the image, the problem is just when the contact has no previous image assigned.

Here is the method in charge of updating the image.

```
public void update(long id, Bitmap bitmap) {       

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    // Picture
    try
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream image = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100, image);

        Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", 
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray());
        ops.add(builder.build());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        this.context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is how I know if the contact belongs to one of the two accounts I mentioned above:

```
// Getting the raw contact id
public static int getRawContactId(Context context, long id) {

    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID };
    String selection = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(id) };
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,
            selection, selectionArgs, null);
    int rawContactId = -1;
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        rawContactId = c.getInt(c
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));
    }

    return rawContactId;
}
```

Here I get the account name for further analysis

```
//...
Uri rawContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);
String[] rawProjection = { RawContacts._ID, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME };
Cursor raw = context.getContentResolver().query(rawContactUri, rawProjection, null, null, null);
if (raw.moveToFirst()) {
    account = raw.getString(1);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that, as you describe, you're **updating** the image
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html#newUpdate(android.net.Uri)

instead of **inserting** a new one
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html#newInsert(android.net.Uri)

If the contact doesn't has a previous image, it's impossible to update the field in the database because it doesn't exists. You should perform an insert operation instead.

*It's debatable if the api method should fail hard throwing an exception at runtime.*

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

After some research as suggested I found an approach that works just fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15145256/2423274

Here is the relevant part:

```
// Create new photo entry

int rawContactId = -1;
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] {id}, null);

if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    rawContactId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));

    if(rawContactId > -1) {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photoBytes)
                        .build());
try {
    resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```