# Adding photo tumbnail to existing Android contact without photo

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I've created a contact in the Android address book programmatically, which has a name and phone number. Now I'd like to add a photo to this contact, but I can't seem to get this working. I don't receive an error message, but the photo doesn't seem to get added.

If I create a new contact WITH photo, the photo is added correctly, and I can update the exisiting photo of this contact as well. Only problem is a contact without photo.

I've already read several solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901457/how-to-set-default-image-to-android-phone-contact-that-has-no-previous-image?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601209/update-contact-image-in-android-contact-provider), and tried several variations based on these answers, but neither works. My best guess is that I'm doing something wrong with the `RAW_CONTACT_ID`. Anyone who can find my bug?

```
private void createNewContact()
{
  ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

  ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
  builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, MY_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
  builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, MY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
  ops.add(builder.build());

  builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
  builder.withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
  builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
  builder.withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, myName);
  ops.add(builder.build());

  builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
  builder.withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
  builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
  builder.withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK);
  builder.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, myPhoneNumber);
  ops.add(builder.build());

  builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
  builder.withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
  builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
  builder.withValue(Photo.PHOTO, myPhotoByteArray);
  ops.add(builder.build());

  try
  {
      context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(AUTHORITY, ops);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      // Handle exception
  }
}



private static final String BASIC_SELECTION = RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "='" + MY_ACCOUNT_TYPE + "'";

private void editContact() {
  ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

  ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI);
  builder.withSelection(BASIC_SELECTION + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null);
  builder.withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, myName);
  ops.add(builder.build());

  builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI);
  builder.withSelection(BASIC_SELECTION + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND " + Phone.TYPE + "='" + Phone.TYPE_WORK + "'", null);
  builder.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, myPhoneNumber);
  ops.add(builder.build());

  if (isContactWithoutPhoto())
  {
    // Contact without photo: insert new photo
    // TODO: this part doesn't work yet!
    int rawContactId = getRawContactId();
    if (rawContactId != -1)
    {
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
        builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(Photo.PHOTO, myPhotoByteArray);
        ops.add(builder.build());
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Contact already has a photo: update
    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(BASIC_SELECTION + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null);
    builder.withValue(Photo.PHOTO, myPhotoBytes);
    ops.add(builder.build());
  }

  try
  {
      context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(AUTHORITY, ops);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      // Handle exception
  }
}

private int getRawContactId()
{
    int rawContactId = -1;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try
    {
        cursor = App.getContext().getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ACCOUNT_TYPE_SELECTION, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            rawContactId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RawContacts._ID));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return rawContactId;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I only need a single contact, which is created a single time, after which it only needs to be updated regularly. This contact is saved on a self-created account with type MY_ACCOUNT_TYPE & name MY_ACCOUNT_NAME. Hence the `builder.withSelection(BASIC_SELECTION` for each update operation, which uses MY_ACCOUNT_TYPE rather than an id.

I have also tried to add that same selection on the 'update photo on existing contact' part, to implement it more like the other 'update' code, because I want to be sure I update the photo ONLY for that single contact:

```
int rawContactId = getRawContactId();
if (rawContactId != -1)
{
    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(BASIC_SELECTION + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null);
    builder.withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
    builder.withValue(Photo.PHOTO, myPhotoByteArray);
    ops.add(builder.build());
```

In this case the app obviously crashes with the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: only updates, deletes, and asserts can have selections`. The id is already collected using the `BASIC_SELECTION`, so I expect the correct contact to be updated in this way anyway.

In case somebody wonders which (static) imports for ContactsContract are used:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;

import static android.provider.ContactsContract.AUTHORITY;
import static android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note;
import static android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import static android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName;
import static android.provider.ContactsContract.Data;
import static android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts;
```

Comment: Can you be explicit about how it doesn't work? For example is there an error message? Does the app crash? Or does the photo just fail to appear on the contact? How did you know that it failed?

Comment: I don't receive an error message, but the photo doesn't seem to get added. (I editted the question directly)

Answer (score 0):

Don't access `CommonDataKinds.Photo` directly, instead use the APIs supplied helper class [`DisplayPhoto`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto).
This helper class will populate both `PHOTO` and `PHOTO_FILE_ID` which is what your code was missing.

try the following:

```
public void setPhoto(long rawContactId, byte[] photo) {
    Uri rawContactPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId), RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(rawContactPhotoUri, "rw");
        OutputStream os = fd.createOutputStream();
        os.write(photo);
        os.close();
        fd.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already found a different solution, but yours seems to be much easier. I'll check it out soon!

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of trial and error I found the RawContactId was not correct.
Finally I came up with this solution: retrieve the RawContacts.CONTACT_ID using PhoneLookup._ID, which can be retrieved by the phoneNumber.

```
// This code stays the same as described in the question (except for some error handling and closing cursors, which I left out for simplicity sake):

private void createNewContact() {
  ...
}

private static final String BASIC_SELECTION = RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "='" + MY_ACCOUNT_TYPE + "'";

private void editContact() {
  ...
  int rawContactId = getRawContactId();
  ...
}

// The different part is the way to retrieve the RawContactId:

private static final ContentResolver CONTENT_RESOLVER = context.getContentResolver();

private int getRawContactId()
{
    String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};
    Cursor cursor = CONTENT_RESOLVER.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, BASIC_SELECTION, null, null);
    String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
    return getRawContactIdWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
}

private int getRawContactIdWithPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    String[] projection = {PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};
    Cursor cursor = CONTENT_RESOLVER.query(uri, projection, BASIC_SELECTION, null, null);
    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID));
    return getRawContactIdWithPhoneLookupId(id);
}

private int getRawContactIdWithPhoneLookupId(int id)
{
    String[] projection = new String[]{RawContacts._ID};
    String selection = RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    Cursor cursor = CONTENT_RESOLVER.query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RawContacts._ID));
}
```